# Liferay Module Project Creation in Liferay 7 Tomcat Server using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, liferay-7, liferay-7.2

I am trying to create a Liferay Module project using Eclipse. I tried by changing the perspective and then File -> New -> Liferay Module Project. The project got successfully created, but when I try to deploy it using the drag and drop on the server, it's not allowing me to do so. Also I guess (when I go through some tutorials) while creating the project, an option to select the Liferay version should be present, which is not available in my case (screenshot is attached).

It took me the whole day and I still am not able to solve it. Any help would be highly appreciated. I am in fact not able to run any runnable jsf project either in Liferay workspace.

Below are the versions that I am using:

- Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) liferay-ce-portal-tomcat-7.3.3-ga4
  Java 1.8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJFVf.png)

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Looks entirely consistent with https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018158871-Creating-Modules-with-Liferay-Developer-Studio .

Comment: You're doing _something_ and _it doesn't work_... Both emphasized parts need more information, otherwise we can only tell to do _something different_

Comment: One thing you could try is to use only: letters and numbers in your folder paths, so avoid using dots and spaces. Also if you provide detailed steps we can happily assist you further